# Is it possible to use US/UK agents (sites or people) for flights to and from third party countries?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, travel-agents

For instance I'm in NZ and want to travel to say US/UK or even other countries. I can of course use NZ agents to plan/book this trip. But not having traveled overseas in the past 4 years I'm not sure if the world has sufficiently changed such that I can look at using agents from other countries  to find better options?

For instance this may be a complete no-brainer as IATA rules may prevent this kind of transaction.

Comment: I've booked flights in other countries using US websites like Kayak.com, I would imagine, it is the same process.

Comment: Why do you think this might even be an issue? (I say this as someone who has recently used a UK travel agent to book a flight for someone flying from India to Germany!)

Answer (score 1):

For the most part there are no legalities that prohibit it. Perhaps some totalitarian countries might restrict their people's air travel buying ability visa the internet (thinking North Korea), but developed nations do not.

Our tour company's primary air ticketing partner is based in the USA, but our clients come from all over the globe.  They have arranged all sorts of flights for our guests, intra-Asia flights for folks from the Australia, Australia to Hawaii flights for guests in UK, US to Canada flights from folks from NZ, etc.

That said, there could be fare offerings that are available for sale only within a specific zone or country.  In these cases you may need to purchase that fare from an agent or OTA within that country (and sometimes have a billing address within that area as well).

There could also be restrictions on foreign card usage on at a specific OTA or airline website.  Though this is usually only effects folks living in countries where credit card fraud is rampant.